# multilevel grouping in MongoDB Query

Tags: mongodb, group-by, grouping, multi-level

I'm trying to write a query where it will give the result of multilevel grouping.

Like below:

```
firstLevel: [
    {
       SecondLevel-1:
       [
              {//Some Data},
              {//Some Data}
       ]
    },
    {
       SecondLevel-2:
       [
              {//Some Data},
              {//Some Data}
       ]
    }
]
```

Below is my MongoPlayGround URL

https://mongoplayground.net/p/b7VzoXavw9r

I'm able to get the first level grouping, although I want the result in the below format.

```
    [
  {
    "section-1": [
      {
        "terminal-1":[
                {
            "_id": ObjectId("5e93fea52f804ab99b12e7c0"),
            "isActive": true,
            "isDelete": false
          },
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5e93fea52f804ab99b12e7c1"),
            "isActive": true,
            "isDelete": false
          }
        ]
      },
      "terminal-2":[
                {
                     "_id": ObjectId("5e93fea52f804ab99b12e7c2"),
                    "isActive": true,
                    "isDelete": true
                }
        ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 1):

- `$group` by `section` and `terminal`, make unique array of `terminal`
- `$group` by `section` and make key value pair of terminal array
- `$arrayToObject` convert key and value array to object
- `$replaceRoot` to replace object in root after converting to object

```
db.settings.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        section: "$section",
        terminal: "$terminal"
      },
      v: {
        $addToSet: {
          _id: "$_id",
          isActive: "$isActive",
          isDelete: "$isDelete"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.section",
      v: {
        $push: { k: "$_id.terminal", v: "$v" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: [[
            {
              k: "$_id",
              v: { $arrayToObject: "$v" }
            }
        ]]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hhaCKMJU4OZ)